# Crystalreport display only once for duplicated record

Tags: crystal-reports

In my crystal report, records are showing like that.

```
NAME    DEPOSIT     REMARK

LUKE    100.00      DECEMBER
LUKE    10.00       NOV
LUKE    10.00       NOV
```

But we have found duplicated record in there. In this case, I don't want to touch my query and want to change only in crystal report. What I want to be is like

```
NAME    DEPOSIT     REMARK

LUKE    100.00      DECEMBER
LUKE     10.00      NOV
```

Any resolution will be appreciated.

Comment: What is your data model? Is there a Deposit_ID unique for each row you'd like to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to achieve this in the Crystal Reports designer, then there is an option "Database" in the menu that says "Select Distinct Records". Try using this it will return you only unique records, but be sure you use the unique field as well in the Details section.

Hope this helps.